# Real-time Video stream to android with camera mounted on toy car

Tags: android, video

We are working on controlling a toy car mounted with a camera with a android mobile. We would like to make it look like a video game with speed meter and battery information displayed in the corner of the screen with the video stream to make it look like a First Person View.

I was wondering how to achieve that with a good range, indoor or outdoor, good fps.

I found out some video transmitter that use UHF but I have no idea how to send that to an android device. Could it be possible to pass by a computer and wi-fi connection.
Maybe sacrifice range and only use wi-fi and a wi-fi extender.

It's hard to find information on not made out-of-the-box solutions. 
I was thinking about encoding the video myself and sending it somehow but it's all new to me.

thanks